# SQL change a query from a specific user to all users

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use sql server and I have the tables:

```
tbl_Message:
id, user_id, group_id
```

Which is a table containing all the message with the details of who wrote the message (user_id) and in which group it was sent (group_id)

```
tbl_GroupUser:
user_id, group_id
```

which is a table containing the users and the groups they are in (each group has more than one user_id and each user has more than one group).

I created a query that return the ratio between the messages the user sent and the the messages he received. I made a query that works for a specific user and I want a query that shows the results for all the user exists. This is the query I made:

```
SELECT CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_Message WHERE user_id = ‘user’)
as decimal) / 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_Message WHERE group_id in 
(SELECT group_id FROM tbl_GroupUser WHERE user_id = ‘user’) and user_id != ‘user’)
```

Example:

tbl_GroupUser

```
user_id | group_id
-------------------
 1      | 1
 2      | 1
```

tbl_Message

```
id | user_id | group_id
-----------------------
1  | 1       | 1
2  | 2       | 1
3  | 2       | 1
```

Will return:

```
user_id | ratio
---------------
1       | 1/2
2       | 2/1
```

Comment: Would you show some sample data and from it what would be the result please?

Comment: I added an example now.

Comment: Wouldn't the result be 1/3 and 2/3? Or are you just looking for the count vs the count of all that aren't that user?

Comment: no, count the messages the user sent vs the messages the user received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me assume that you have a `users` table.

```
select u.*, s.num_sent, r.num_received,
       s.num_sent / nullif(r.num_received, 0) as ratio
from users u left join
     (select user_id, count(*) as num_sent
      from tbl_Message m
      group by user_id
     ) s
     on s.user_id = u.user_id left join
     (select gu.user_id, count(*) as num_received
      from tbl_Message m join
           tbl_GroupUser gu
           on m.group_id = gu.group_id
      group by gu.user_id
     ) r
     on r.user_user = u.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT user_ID, 1.0 *  A.B / COUNT(*)
FROM tbl_Message M
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM tbl_Message
    WHERE group_ID IN (
        SELECT group_ID 
        FROM tbl_GroupUser
        WHERE user_ID = M.user_ID)
    AND user_ID <> M.user_ID) A(B)
GROUP BY user_ID, A.B
ORDER BY user_ID;
```

Alternatively, if you want the actual amount overall, it would be `1.0 * COUNT(*) / A.B` and remove the line `AND user_ID <> M.user_ID` (this produces 1/3 and 2/3).